# UNET source separation shape incompatibility, incorrect shapes concatenating

Tags: python, shapes, padding, unet-neural-network

`class AudioUNet(nn.Module):
def **init**(self, input_channels, start_neurons):
super(AudioUNet, self).**init**()

```
    self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(input_channels, start_neurons, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons, start_neurons, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Dropout2d(0.25)
    )

    self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons, start_neurons * 2, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 2, start_neurons * 2, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Dropout2d(0.5)
    )

    self.conv3 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 2, start_neurons * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 4, start_neurons * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Dropout2d(0.5)
    )

    self.conv4 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 4, start_neurons * 8, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 8, start_neurons * 8, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Dropout2d(0.5)
    )

    self.convm = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 8, start_neurons * 16, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 16, start_neurons * 16, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    )

    self.deconv4 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(start_neurons * 16, start_neurons * 8, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1,
                                      output_padding=1)
    self.uconv4 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout2d(0.5),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 16, start_neurons * 16, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 16, start_neurons * 8, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    )

    self.deconv3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(start_neurons * 8, start_neurons * 4, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1,
                                      output_padding=1)
    self.uconv3 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout2d(0.5),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 8, start_neurons * 8, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 8, start_neurons * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    )

    self.deconv2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(start_neurons * 4, start_neurons * 2, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1,
                                      output_padding=1)
    self.uconv2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout2d(0.5),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 4, start_neurons * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 4, start_neurons * 2, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    )

    self.deconv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(start_neurons * 2, start_neurons, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1,
                                      output_padding=1)
    self.uconv1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout2d(0.5),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 2, start_neurons * 2, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(start_neurons * 2, start_neurons, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    )

    self.output_layer = nn.Conv2d(start_neurons, 1, kernel_size=1)
```

`

I get this error, I tried padding but i cant seem to figure it out.

uconv3_out = torch.cat([deconv3_out, conv3_out], dim=1)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 116 but got size 117 for tensor number 1 in the list.

This is the activation unit:

```
def forward(self, x):

x=x.view(x.shape[0],1,x.shape[1],x.shape[2])

conv1_out = self.conv1(x)
conv2_out = self.conv2(conv1_out)
conv3_out = self.conv3(conv2_out)
conv4_out = self.conv4(conv3_out)
convm_out = self.convm(conv4_out)

deconv4_out = self.deconv4(convm_out)
uconv4_out = torch.cat((deconv4_out, conv4_out), dim=1)
uconv4_out = self.uconv4(uconv4_out)

deconv3_out = self.deconv3(uconv4_out)
print("deconv3_out size:", deconv3_out.size())
print("conv3_out size:", conv3_out.size())
uconv3_out = torch.cat([deconv3_out, conv3_out], dim=1)
uconv3_out = self.uconv3(uconv3_out)

deconv2_out = self.deconv2(uconv3_out)
uconv2_out = torch.cat([deconv2_out, conv2_out], dim=1)
uconv2_out = self.uconv2(uconv2_out)

deconv1_out = self.deconv1(uconv2_out)
uconv1_out = torch.cat([deconv1_out, conv1_out], dim=1)
uconv1_out = self.uconv1(uconv1_out)

output = torch.sigmoid(self.output_layer(uconv1_out))

return output
```

Tried applying padding and such, but I cant seem to figure it out.

Please help